# Select div by contains with css

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a simple markup and I would like to select a div by it's content. Here is my code...

```
<div class="parent">
    <h4>Child of parent</h4>
    <div>
        <div>I'm red!</div>
        <h4>I'm red's sister</h4>
        <div>I'm blue!</div>
        <h4>I'm blue's brother</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

and selecting `<div>I'm red!</div>` with the following CSS...

```
div:contains("I'm red!") {
    color: red;
}
```

since `contains()` is deprecated or never got implemented, I can do the following...

```
.parent div:nth-child(1) {
    color: red;
}
.parent dh4:nth-child(2) {
    color: red;
}
```

to target just the first two elements, and it worked, but I would like to know if it is a way I can target just the first two element which happened to be `<div>` and `<h4>` in one `CSS` line of code?  I need to do this without `javascript`. Eventually I need to target just 3rd and 4th.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Use `:nth-child(-n+2)`.

For the 3rd and 4th you can use `:nth-child(n+3):nth-child(-n+4)` or just `:nth-child(-n+4)` and let specificity fix it for you.

The logic is easy:

- `:nth-child(-n+a)` selects the a-th element and its previous siblings
- `:nth-child(n+a)` selects the a-th element and its following siblings
- `:nth-child(n+a):nth-child(-n+b)` selects the a-th and b-th elements, and the siblings in-between.

```css
.parent > div > :nth-child(-n+4) {
  color: blue;
}
.parent > div > :nth-child(-n+2) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <h4>Child of parent</h4>
  <div>
    <div>I'm red!</div>
    <h4>I'm red's sister</h4>
    <div>I'm blue!</div>
    <h4>I'm blue's brother</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I understand your question. You can do that to have it on one line anyway.

```
.parent div:nth-child(1), .parent dh4:nth-child(2) {color: red;}
```

or you could apply a red class on the first two divs and do :

```
.red{color:red}
```